# Different Color Codings For birthdays

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to implement different colors for each birthday on the calendar provided by FullCalendar. Can anyone help us to resolve.

Comment: show us what you've tried yet.

Comment: Welcome to SO, here is [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I am not getting i had to modify it

Comment: I am not getting where i had to modify it @kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an event's color when initializing fullcalendar.

```
color
```

is a property on the event object. You can see the [documentation here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/).

Here's an example of my fullcalendar being initialized with two different color events:

```js
vm.ele.fullCalendar({
  contentHeight: 'auto'
  dayNames: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
  defaultView: vm.calDefaultView,
  eventLimit: false,
  events: [{
    title: 'Event 1',
    start: '2015-11-17',
    color: '#ffffff'
  }, {
    title: 'Event 2',
    start: '2015-11-17',
    color: '#000000'
  }],
  firstDay: 1,
  fixedWeekCount: false,
  header: {
    left: 'title',
    center: '',
    right: 'basicDay,basicWeek,month prev,next'
  }
  weekends: false
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Brandon , here you provided the thing for manuaaly making the colors change. Suppose there is set of 100 events, how can we make it dynamically...!!!!!

Comment: Hmm. You might be able to access the event and change the color, but I'm not sure. I'd recommend posting another question for that situation if one doesn't already exist.